# Can access web.properties but not files error - using Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, python

I'm using Office365-REST-Python-Client to access some files from Sharepoint through a Python script (using App-only method)

a code example would be this:

```
credentials = ClientCredential(x, y)
ctx = ClientContext(z).with_credentials(credentials)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web site title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))

response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)

print(bytes_file_obj.getvalue())
```

My problem is that I can get the web.properties (it shows the title in this example) but when I try to do anything related to the file I get an error saying the file does not exist:

```
b'{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file /PATH/TO/FILE/ does not exist."}}}'
```

I try creating different files on different locations but the error is the same, some of those would be

```
z = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/' 
z = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test'
relative_url = '/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/TestBook.xlsx'
relative_url = '/sites/test/Shared Documents/TestBook.xlsx'
relative_url = '/sites/test/SharedDocuments/TestBook.xlsx'

z = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/' 
z = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com' 
relative_url = '/Shared%20Documents/Book544.xlsx'
relative_url = '/Shared%20Documents/TestTest/TestBook222.xlsx'
relative_url = '/Shared Documents/TestTest/TestBook222.xlsx'
```

For reference, the paths taken from Sharepoint file properties would be like this:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Book544.xlsx

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/TestTest/TestBook222.xlsx

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/TestBook.xlsx

For this test the xml permissions on /_layouts/15/appinv.aspx are like this (on tenant-admin.sharepoint.com and tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test respectively):

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

and

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant/sites/test" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

---

I run out of ideas on how to solve this. How can I access the Sharepoint file using the Rest API after I already successfully pass the authentication part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I wrote the name of the SharePoint tenant on

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

When I use literally "http://sharepoint/content/tenant" the rest of the script works fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You web.config should have below correct entry.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Your CSOM code should be as follows:

```
credentials = ClientCredential(x, y)
ctx = ClientContext(z).with_credentials(credentials)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web site title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))

File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/Shared Documents/testbook.xlsx");

clientContext.Load(file);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

You'll get your file data in file object